# The set of all Yang-Mills connections is infinite dimensional

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, gauge-theory

I am reading Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis (7-Ed)* and having a question about the Yang-Mills functional (page 182).

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $E$ be a metric bundle where the structure group is $SO(n)$ ($n$ is the fiber dimension). Let $\mathscr{G}$ be the gauge group, i.e., the set of sections of $Aut(E)$. $\mathscr{G}$ acts on the set of all metric connections by conjugation.

Jost first showed that the set of Yang-Mills connections (the solution of Yang-Mills functional) is invariant under this action. Then he wrote

> **Corollary 4.2.3** The space of Yang–Mills connections on a given metric
> vector bundle E of rank $ \ge 2$ is infinite dimensional, unless
> empty.

First, is the set of all Yang-Mills functional an affine space (so that it makes sense to talk about dimension)? If it is an affine space, then why it is infinite dimensional when the rank $\ge 2$?

For the second question, my idea is that we can *locally* change the connection by choosing a gauge transformation $g \in \mathscr{G}$ such that $g(x)$ is the identity map outsides a neighborhood of $x_0 \in M$. But for the first one, I have no clue now.

Any comment is appreciated!

Comment: I would say that the reason is as follows: when the rank is $1$, the gauge group acts trivially, so what I'm about to say would not apply. But when the rank is greater than $1$, the gauge group acts non-trivially. So given a Yang-Mills connection, its orbit under $\mathscr{G}$ is an entire family of solutions, and since the automorphism group is infinite dimensional (it is an infinite dimensional Lie group), so is the space of solutions to the Yang-Mills equation.

Comment: Do you know that in topology one has a notion of dimension for a general topological space (even several notions)?

Comment: @QuaereVerum Thank you for the comment. This is my first time hearing that the automorphism group is an infinite dimensional Lie group. Could you provide any reference? I suppose that I can understand your comment once having enough background knowledge (the topology on automorphism group, the dimension of the space of YM connections, etc).

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately I don’t know that. So here, the dimension of the space of YM connections is not the one for a vector (affine) space or a manifold? Or we can somehow give the space of YM connections a topology and then consider “the dimension of the topological space”?

Comment: Of course, you need a topology on that space. It is not a manifold but manifold points form an open and dense subset. Topology on the space of YM connections is discussed in various books on the subject, say Freed and Uhlenbeck or Donaldson and Kronheimer.

Comment: It should probably be noted that those books discuss the *moduli space* of Yang-Mills connection. That is, Yang-Mills connections modulo the action of the gauge group. In this post, we're talking about the actual space of Yang-Mills connections, before quotienting.